# Xcode 8 build failed: Signing for "ProjectName" requires a development team

Tags: ios, xcode

I recently downloaded a tutorial project from web and gonna follow the tutorial to try some features. When I build the project the follow message appeared:

```
Signing for "ProjectName" requires a development team.
Select a development team in the project editor.
```

For my real project I will select my development team but this one is only for testing and tutorial purpose. Do I need to select a team in order to run the app? If I choose a personal team, another error thrown out:
Failed to create provisioning profile.

```
The app ID "xx.xx" cannot be registered to your development team. Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again.

No profiles for 'xx.xx' were found
Xcode couldn't find a provisioning profile matching 'xx.xx'.
```

Seems Xcode 7 can build the project without specifying a team.

Comment: If you are performing testing, then change the bundle identifier. Select personal team and run the app on device.

Comment: Is it mandatory to choose a team in Xcode 8?

Comment: If you want to run on device, then it is mandatory.

Answer (score 3):

Follow the following steps:

1. Go on `Project Main Source File`
2. Go in `General` Tab
3. Under `General` Go into `Signing`  where you have `status in red warning`
4. Select Your Correct `Team` and Tick `Automatically manage Signing`